# Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test p-value evaluation

Tags: python, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, two-sample

I'm using python's scpipy implementation of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test (ks_2samp).

Q1: Why are my p-values in the examples below so low, specifically on the first example?

Q2: Can I compare the results of two independent ks-tests e.g. compare p-values of example 1 and example 2 if the variable being tested is the same in both tests?

```
   Example 1: Ks_2sampResult(statistic=1.0, pvalue=3.3575919359263295e-06)
   s1 = [166.1012, 218.5702, 105.437, 180.384]
   s2 = [     1651.3443,          2151.7857,          3585.2535,
              1810.3321,          1371.2226,          1427.3859,
              1936.5265,          1540.6437,          2015.9198,
     1822.0279999999998,          1679.7153,          1603.0603,
              1724.5565,          2106.0322,          2452.3095,
              1502.3622,          1311.8174,          1582.9067,
              1452.2648,          1762.5133,          1847.0054,
              1960.3908,           974.8304,          1337.5023,
              1719.4076,          2417.7195,           1535.014,
              1318.9727,          1661.1111,          2377.7883,
                1443.69,          2279.6892,          1990.0452,
              2727.1002,          1777.3109,           2077.305,
              1836.0129,          1546.6872,          2088.7097,
              2283.3706,          1831.3387,          3677.7951,
              2015.8617,          1786.6324,          1432.2034,
              1580.0954,          1772.9689,          1242.3729,
              1827.1277,          1468.8121,          1327.5178,
              1382.3529,          1054.0694,           673.9015,
              1931.7032,          2073.6708,          1408.8855,
              1794.9474,          1512.4106]

Example 2 Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.9552238805970149, pvalue=2.220446049250313e-16)
s1 = [     921.0896,          1395.2823,           868.5006,
          2270.2785,          1931.0436,           594.1614,
          2715.5172,          5823.1759,          1392.1188,
          2535.9649,           556.7188,            45.9976,
          3313.4697,           167.3922,          4329.2824,
          1765.7478,          2569.2585,          1629.7814,
          2590.0768,          1011.0524,          1805.2208,
          2033.4327,          1673.1377,          2922.9487,
          1800.8324,           546.7342,          1276.9231,
          2482.8393,          5509.3764,          1212.3673,
          2103.7291,           653.1032,  5324.699000000001,
          1886.8258,          1917.2108,          2563.8736,
           1946.161,          1307.1957,           1748.371,
          3465.8982,           634.4227,          1251.0949,
          2600.0939,           380.9129,          1426.2991,
          2599.2857,          2919.1729,          1611.0894,
          2214.2857, 1487.8339999999994,          2339.7213,
           768.8949,          2632.8928,          2721.7125,
          2699.2262,           2684.947,          1497.7679,
          1160.7143,          2478.0488,          2098.8397,
          2072.1063,          1772.1107,          2836.7866,
          2443.6479,          3405.1447,          2887.6404,
          1317.9153]
s2 = [    5410.2342,          8780.0325,          8682.7957,
          8991.1439, 5421.2919999999995,           6093.361,
          6552.1807,          5014.7906,          4876.1792,
          7609.2328,          8175.1509,          8942.3942,
          6296.9188,          5703.2596,          6891.4217,
          6011.0236,          7258.0277,          6312.3277,
          8407.6655,         11469.6486,           8352.539,
          5152.3633,          8603.4665,          9730.2221,
          6879.9688,          7117.7663,          9081.9328,
          7439.1052,          6132.0988,          9237.7788,
           7740.576,          7129.8557,          7712.2172,
          5172.8793,          8455.8824,          9253.9007,
          5590.3537,          7109.7072,          7699.6928,
          9332.5876,          7527.5478,          6363.9722,
          6839.5963,          8687.2322,          7330.9793,
          4477.8459,          7189.8254,             5500.0,
          7725.3989,          6382.9326,          7878.6677,
  9625.386999999999,          5978.3722,         10074.7022,
          6807.7572,          6310.2885,          6943.5241,
          7213.1733,          9182.2234]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll accept BruceET answer as it provided some knowledge about the first question. However, my second question is still unanswered. I've dug a little bit deeper and what I was searching for was adjusted p-values (padj or q-values), I'm still a bit confused about it but I'll open a new topic where I try to explain it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the P-value of the K-S test is nearly $0$
because the two samples are quite different, as shown by the
summaries and boxplots below. I am puzzled why you are surprised
at this result. Am I missing some crucial part of your Question?

```
s1 = c(166.1012, 218.5702, 105.437, 180.384)
s2 = c(   1651.3443,          2151.7857,          3585.2535,
          1810.3321,          1371.2226,          1427.3859,
          1936.5265,          1540.6437,          2015.9198,
 1822.0279999999998,          1679.7153,          1603.0603,
          1724.5565,          2106.0322,          2452.3095,
          1502.3622,          1311.8174,          1582.9067,
          1452.2648,          1762.5133,          1847.0054,
          1960.3908,           974.8304,          1337.5023,
          1719.4076,          2417.7195,           1535.014,
          1318.9727,          1661.1111,          2377.7883,
            1443.69,          2279.6892,          1990.0452,
          2727.1002,          1777.3109,           2077.305,
          1836.0129,          1546.6872,          2088.7097,
          2283.3706,          1831.3387,          3677.7951,
          2015.8617,          1786.6324,          1432.2034,
          1580.0954,          1772.9689,          1242.3729,
          1827.1277,          1468.8121,          1327.5178,
          1382.3529,          1054.0694,           673.9015,
          1931.7032,          2073.6708,          1408.8855,
          1794.9474,          1512.4106)

summary(s1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  105.4   150.9   173.2   167.6   189.9   218.6 
summary(s2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  673.9  1460.5  1762.5  1787.9  2003.0  3677.8
```

Notice that the maximum of `s1` is smaller than the minimum of `s2`.

```
boxplot(s1,s2, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

The implementation of the K-S test in R gives essentially the same
P-value as you got in Python. Everything here seems consistent with your
results for your
first example. The null hypothesis that the samples come from the same
population is very strongly rejected.

```
ks.test(s1, s2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  s1 and s2
D = 1, p-value = 3.358e-06
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

**Addendum** per Comment:

Repeatedly testing $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ vs $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2$ at 5% level for two normal samples of size $n=10,$ both from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=15).$

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^6, t.test(rnorm(10, 100, 15), rnorm(10, 100, 15))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.04856               # aprx 5%
summary(pv)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000014 0.2515800 0.5004733 0.5009230 0.7503288 0.9999988 
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v=0.05, col="red")
```

The P-values have a standard uniform distribution, their mean is 1/2, and the (true) $H_0$ is rejected about 5% of the time (for P-values to
the left of the vertical red line in the histogram).

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. 
Regarding my first question, I do understand that the distributions are different and so the p-value should be close to 0. 
I'm confused because the results I get from ks-test's, the p-value is never even close to alpha=0.05, so can we assume all the tests I've done are statistically significantly different distributions, or should this alpha vary according to specific data?

Comment: If the null hypothesis (that the two population means are equal) then a test at the 5% level will reject with probability 0.05. If your test statistic is continuous, then the distribution of P-values will be UNIF(0,1). So the P-value will be less than 0.05 in 5% of the tests over the long run. The P-value will seldom be near 5%. On average the P-value will be $1/2. $  See Addendum to my Answer.

Comment: @beerzy The samples are super different, so there's basically no chance that both were drawn from the population. The p-value near zero is the formal way of saying that there is "basically no chance".